# Can't inject $filter when creating a filter, unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting an error when inject $filter in angular, I'm new to angular, so probably I'm missing something. This is my code

```
(function () {
   var dateTimeLocalFilter = function ($filter) {
       return function(timestamp) {
           if(timestamp == null){ return ""; }

           var date = $filter('date')(new Date(timestamp),
               'MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss');

           var now = new Date(date);

           return now.getTime();
       };
   };
   dateTimeLocalFilter.$inject = ["$filter"];
   angular.module("MyApp").filter("dateTimeLocalFilter", dateTimeLocalFilter);
});
```

And I'm getting this error:
    Unknown provider: dateTimeLocalFilterProvider <-NaNateTimeLocalFilter

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You are getting the error when you try to use your filter? The code in your example should end with `})();` or it will not be executed.

Comment: That error message isn't for `$filter`. It's for `NaNateTimeLocalFilter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was lacking `();` at the end, and because of that the code wan't executed and filter wasn't created. Thanks tasseKATT!